# Something like optionalQuotedString in pyparsing?

Tags: python, parsing, pyparsing

In my parser I have multiple occurrences of

```
expression = quotedString(pattern) | Word(pattern)
```

and I was wondering if there is some built-in  class I've missed for that or if I have define it myself. In case of the second, what would the best option?

Comment: Sorry that the code is not formatted properly, I thought I added the four spaces...?

Comment: you can always [`edit`](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/9745143/edit) your question and fix formatting errors.

Comment: You might need to revisit your grammar. `quotedString('xyzzy')` will parse any single or double quoted string, and returned the string as a token with the results name 'xyzzy' (like named groups in re) - the parsing of this expression has nothing do with the string 'xyzzy'. `Word('xyzzy')` will parse any word composed of x's, y's, and z's, the unique set of letters in 'xyzzy'. The argument to Word is a string containing the valid word characters. Or you can pass two strings, where the first string is the set of valid initial characters, and the second is the set of valid body characters.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Good catch! Thankfully I only have to change J.F.Sebastians function now. I guess I should use Forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this:

```
def quotedStringOrWord(pattern):
    return quotedString(pattern) | Word(pattern)
```

Comment: Yes, a simple function was probably what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Old thread I know, but you can reuse your expressions in other expressions.

```
optionalQuotedString = QuotedString(pattern) | Word(pattern)

expression1 = optionalQuotedString
expression2 = Literal('>') + optionalQuotedString
```

Might be a little neater than a function, but does the same thing.